# Touchend or Touchcancel not fire on iPad JQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ipad, web-applications

Really test a lot of time, getting frustrated.

I want to hide the Jquery Dialog content when dragging/moving (Touchmove) the dialog, then showing back the content when the drag/move is stop (touchend/touchcancel).

I can hide the content when dragging(touchdown), but cannot showing up back the content after stop.

So far I realize it can only perform "mousedown" and "mouseout" which mean if I don't move it, only touch it then leave my finger, the content show up back....

Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
var drag_keyboard = $( "#keyboard" ).dialog({width: 670, height: 300});
drag_keyboard.parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').bind( "touchstart", function(e){
$('#keyboard').hide();
});

drag_keyboard.parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').bind( "touchmove", function(e){
e.preventDefault();             
});

drag_keyboard.parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').bind( "touchcancel", function(e){    
$('#keyboard').show();  
});

drag_keyboard.parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').bind( "touchend", function(e){
$('#keyboard').show();      
});
```

Comment: why you don't you a lib with better support for mobile likes JQueryMobile? Pls have a look at this: http://www.devinrolsen.com/basic-jquery-touchmove-event-setup/

Comment: Thanks for suggestion and reference. But the problem really here on the mobile devices, the mouseout/mouseleave/mouseup effect cannot trigger after the mousemove.